# “Class” versus “namedtuple” to simulate a deck in Python

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, collections, namedtuple

Several books (or tutorials) define a card and a deck in the following fashion:

```
import random

class Card(object):
    """ A card object with a suit and rank."""

    RANKS = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13)

    SUITS = ('Spades', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Clubs')

    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        """Creates a card with the given rank and suit."""
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit

    def __str__(self):
        """Returns the string representation of a card."""
        if self.rank == 1:
            rank = 'Ace'
        elif self.rank == 11:
            rank = 'Jack'
        elif self.rank == 12:
            rank = 'Queen'
        elif self.rank == 13:
            rank = 'King'
        else:
            rank = self.rank
        return str(rank) + ' of ' + self.suit

import random

class Deck(object):
    """ A deck containing 52 cards."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Creates a full deck of cards."""
        self._cards = []
        for suit in Card.SUITS:
            for rank in Card.RANKS:
                c = Card(rank, suit)
                self._cards.append(c)

    def shuffle(self):
        """Shuffles the cards."""
        random.shuffle(self._cards)

    def deal(self):
        """Removes and returns the top card or None 
        if the deck is empty."""
        if len(self) == 0:
           return None
        else:
           return self._cards.pop(0)

    def __len__(self):
       """Returns the number of cards left in the deck."""
       return len(self._cards)

    def __str__(self): 
        """Returns the string representation of a deck."""
        result = ''
        for c in self._cards:
            result = self.result + str(c) + '\n'
        return result
```

A recent book I am reading defines it as:

```
import collections

Card = collections.namedtuple('Card', ['rank', 'suit'])

class FrenchDeck:
    ranks = [str(n) for n in range(2, 11)] + list('JQKA')
    suits = 'spades diamonds clubs hearts'.split()

    def __init__(self):
        self._cards = [Card(rank, suit) for suit in self.suits
                                        for rank in self.ranks]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._cards)

    def __getitem__(self, position):
        return self._cards[position]
```

If nothing else, this version “seems” less verbose. (But it is not my concern for this question. As they are, it is wrong to compare the length of the codes.)

For this example, and perhaps in general, what are the pros and cons of defining a card as namedtuple versus class?

If the answer is simply one is mutable and other is not, what are my reasons to care about that?

Is one version more Pythonic than the other?

Comment: A `namedtuple` has immutable instances and probably doesn't contain any user-defined functions. A class is probably not immutable (at least not very immutable) and you can put in it a bunch of useful functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The named tuple really is only less verbose in that you don't need the boilerplate `__init__` method that the class has.

OK, so the implementation you show doesn't have a lengthy `__str__` function either, but then again its representation as a string doesn't have the features required of the class version, so it's not reasonable to compare the amounts of code.

The important difference between the two is that `namedtuple` gives you immutable objects, whereas the class shown above is mutable (and would require extra code to make it immutable).

Extra functions (as khelwood mentions in a comment) can for example be dealt with by combining the two:

```
class Card(collections.namedtuple('CardBase', ['rank', 'suit'])):
    def __str__(self):
        # code to say "Ace of spades" goes here
```

The result still has read-only `.rank` and `.suit` attributes, although it does now has its own dictionary for other mutable attributes so it's not really an immutable type any more. If you're *intending* to mix read-only with read-write attributes then you're probably better off using `@property` than using `namedtuple`, but if you just want to stick some convenience functions on something that's otherwise a good fit for `namedtuple`, then this works.

A final possible disadvantage of using `namedtuple` is that the result is a tuple. That is to say, it can be accessed using `[0]` and `[1]`, card objects can be added together using `+` with meaningless results, and everything else tuples do. It isn't usually actively harmful to have nonsense/irrelevant operations on your objects, but it's not good either because it can bloat your auto-generated documentation, make mistakes harder to find, and other such annoyances. It's also harder to change a published interface with at lot of guff in it, because once you publish it someone might use it.

Comment: Although you lose some of the advantatges of a `namedtuple` if you don't say `__slots__=()` in the class definition.

Comment: @ppperry: good point, it would have been easier for me to just add that than to say what I said about no longer being immutable!

Comment: In addition to losing \_\_slots\_\_, you're lost all the capabilities of the inherited tuple.  Unpacking with ``rank, suit = card``; hashability for:  ``somedict[card]=value``, ordering with ``card1 < card`` and ``sorted(cards)``.